# JQuery AJAX 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've created a log-in page that uses PHP and JQuery. The problem is, I'm encountering a **403 Forbidden** error every time JQuery $.ajax tries to access the user_login.php file.

Below are my current codes:

**user_index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Foot Steps Philippines -- User Log-in</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/user_login_style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="user_login.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="login_wrapper">
    <h3>Log-In</h3>
    <form id="fsp_login_form" name="fsp_login_form" action="user_login.php" method="POST">
        <input type="email" name="fsp_email" id="fsp_email" placeholder="E-mail Address" />
        <input type="password" name="fsp_password" id="fsp_password" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="submit" name="fsp_login" id="fsp_login" value="Log-In" />
        <h4 id="login_message"></h4>
    </form>
    <div class="links">
        <a href="">Forgot Password?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="note">*To register, please e-mail us at contact@footsteps.ph</div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**user_login.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fsp_login_form").submit(function(){
            $('#login_message').html("Please wait...");
            var action = $('#fsp_login_form').attr('action');
            var form_data = {
                fsp_email: $('#fsp_email').val(),
                fsp_password: $('#fsp_password').val(),
                is_ajax: 1
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: action,
                data: form_data,
                dataType: "text",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                success: function(response) {
                    if ( response == 'success' ) {
                        $('#login_message').html("Login successful!");
                        setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = 'user_cpanel.php'; }, 2000);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#login_message').html("Login failed!");
                    }
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    //$('#login_message').html(err.responseText);
                    alert(err.responseText);
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**user_login.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include 'conn.php';

$is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
$res = "";

if ( isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax ) {
    $email_address = $_REQUEST['fsp_email'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['fsp_password'];

    // Protect to MySQL injection.
    $email_address = stripslashes($email_address);
    $email_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email_address);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email_address = '".$email_address."' AND password = '".$password."'";

    if ( $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) ) {
        if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
            $client_id = 0;
            $premium = 0;
            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
                $client_id = $row['id'];
                $premium = $row['premium_member'];
            }
            $_SESSION['client'] = $client_id;
            $_SESSION['premium'] = $premium;
            $res = "success";
        }
        else {
            $res = "failed";
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
        $res = "failed";
    }
}
else {
    $res = "failed";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
echo $res;
?>
```

**conn.php**
*Note: I intentionally used my localhost database config. I already adjusted it when I uploaded it to my web hosting server.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "footstep_db");

// Check connection.
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else {
    // nothing to do.
}
?>
```

All files are at the same directory and all have 0644 permission.
Do you have any idea guys on how to fix the error?
By the way, my log-in page is functioning perfectly when running in localhost. But its not working when uploaded with my web hosting server.
I don't have access to my web hosting's PHP config file and Apache config file so as much as possible, please try not to give a solution that requires reconfiguration of PHP and Apache.

Thanks :-)

Comment: [CORS](https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=cr&ei=0SrWUq-ECMHdoASZpIGgDw#q=CORS)

Comment: @remus why would you think this is CORS issue? The form's action (which is also used for AJAX) specifies URI on current host.

Comment: @MikeBrant because there's a lot of code here, but not enough to specifically narrow down the error, particularly that there's no output from `alert(err.responseText);`. Percentage chance is high that the CORS header is set incorrectly (or missing).

Comment: Do you have any http authentication, htaccess, or use access control code that is not shown here? The code from the script itself does not show anywhere where a 403 header would be set.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with CORS since all my files are in the same domain.

Comment: @Everard Try encodeURIComponent() your data before sending it...

Comment: @MikeBrant I have a .htaccess file in my web hosting server but it is empty.

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness I tried it but nothing happens.
`$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: encodeURIComponent(action),
    data: form_data,
    dataType: "text",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",`

Comment: @Everard No, no, the data you're passing! I'll put it as an answer so you see what I mean...

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness Do you mean this one? `data: form_data`

Comment: Can you post the full error message ?

Comment: Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /user_login.php
on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved!
I just ask my web hosting to create an exception for my domain.
I think the mod_security setting of their server causes the 403 Forbidden Error.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I mean:

```
        var form_data = {
            fsp_email: encodeURIComponent($('#fsp_email').val()),
            fsp_password: encodeURIComponent($('#fsp_password').val()),
            is_ajax: 1
        };
```

Comment: @Everard Ok, anyways remember to urldecode() it with php when you receive it.

Comment: I also tried changing $_REQUEST to $_POST but still no effect.

Answer (score 0):

What web server are you using?

In order to debug this, I would try the following (create a backup first if you cannot reverse these commands):

Apache (Ubuntu - family):

```
chown www-data:www-data user_login.php
chmod 777 user_login.php
```

Apache (CentOS - family):

```
chown httpd:httpd user_login.php
chmod 777 user_login.php
```

And try again. Also, double check that your script is looking in the right place for your file (chdir if required).

If you are still getting 403 forbidden, check your web server access.log for corresponding entries and they should give you the hint what went wrong.